# Angular + RequireJs: Resolve templateUrls of directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-directive

I use angularjs and requirejs in my spa. For the organization of imports and so on I use require. In requirejs I can use e.g. baseUrl: Every import path is resolved with the baseUrl. Now I would like to resolve the templateUrls the same way. Therefore I can use e.g.:

```
templateUrl = requirejs.toUrl("modules/test/chuck.directive.html")
```

The problem that I would like to resolve every templateUrl of every directive this way.

So: Is there a possibility to jump into the template loading process of directives in angular and run the above code?

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would decorate [$templateRequest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest) service if you know for sure that you want to intercept all template loading requests and modify template URL. Something like this:

```
.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$templateRequest', function($delegate) {
        return function(tpl, ignoreRequestError) {
            tpl = requirejs.toUrl(tpl); // modify original tpl
            return $delegate.call(this, tpl, ignoreRequestError);
        };
    });
})
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try it.